# I want to take string and integer together so that if user enters add y then it perform add and if set x then initialize the value

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
​
public class Solution {
​
    static long maximumProgramValue(int n) {
        long x=0l,y=0l;
        long count=0l;
        while(n!=0) {
            String s=scanner.nextLine();
            if(s.next().equals("add")) {
                y=s.nextLong();
                x=x+y;
            } else {
                y=s.nextLong();
            }
            if(count < x)
            count=x;
            n--;
        }
        return count ;
    }
    ​
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ​
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])*");
        long result = maximumProgramValue(n);
        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

​
I am getting this error please help

```
Solution.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
            if(s.next().equals("add"))
                ^
  symbol:   method next()
  location: variable s of type String
Solution.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
                y=s.nextLong();
                   ^
  symbol:   method nextLong()
  location: variable s of type String
Solution.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
              y=s.nextLong();   
                 ^
  symbol:   method nextLong()
  location: variable s of type String
3 errors
Exit Status
```

Comment: Please look at [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
 if(s.next().equals("add"))
```

should be

```
 if("add".equals(s))
```

`s` is of type `String` already. There's no use of `next()` method call on it.

You should convert `String` to `long` as follows

```
y = Long.parseLong(s);
```

Comment: it is saying can not find symbol s

Comment: and what about s.nextLong(); ?

Comment: You are invking `next` and `nextLong` which `String` doesn't have.

Comment: so how can I get the value of integer when user enters add 5, i have got add but what about 5

Comment: so how can I do this ?

Comment: Shanu, read [What is a Help Vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire). You've got one here -- don't feed it.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't understand the downvote though.